# How to override what happens when boost::serialize gets a POINTER to an object

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, boost-serialization

Hey so I understand boost serializes pointers automatically as long as you've defined the serialization function for the object it's pointing to, but

**what do I do if I want to write a boost serialization function that takes a `myClass pointer`?**

I don't want the boost to do the default action of saving the object that's pointed to and then restoring the pointer to point to that. I want the boost to do something different.

Comment: Was there a reason you can't just dereference the pointer, or am I missing something?

Comment: What "something different" do you want the serialize function to do in that event? Since you control the serialization of each member, can't you simply see the pointer and do the "something different" instead of passing it to the archive?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a behaviour that is different from the normal pointer serialization for your special class, you have two options:

Maybe you can adjust the serialize() methods of all structs/classes that contain your myClass pointer in order to achieve the behaviour that you want. However, if you have many such pointers around, this won't be an option. Another possibility might be to use a free function as described in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html (written for the myClass pointer).

The other option only works if you are using no more than one archive type (e.g. the binary archive). You can derive from the archive classes and add an overload for the method save (and load, respectively).

Comment: yeah i'm stuck with the second option I guess, any links to more info on how to do it/why I can only do it with one archive?

Comment: I suggest to use the debbugger to follow through the method calls in the archive you're working with. However, if you need it for more than one archive - why don't you go with option 1? (Can you specify what exactly you would like to do?)